# how to increase percent value with javascript

Tags: jquery

I am using a progressbar which grows dynamically.
Below the progressbar is the value in percent, which is also generated dynamically.

```
$('.progress-bar').animate({ width: '100%' }, {
    duration:2000,
    step: function(now, fx) {
        if (fx.prop == 'width') {
            var newval = Math.round(now * 100) / 100 + '%';
            $([this, $(this).nextAll('.count')[0]]).html(newval);
        }
    }
});
```

This is what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/zjdBh/34/

How can i get rid of the percent value in the progressbar? The percent below should stay intact, but the textvalue in the progressbar should disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.progress-bar').animate(
    {width:'100%'}, 
    {
        duration:2000,
        step: function(now, fx) {
            if(fx.prop == 'width') {
               var newval = Math.round(now * 100) / 100 + '%';                    
               $([$(this).nextAll('.count')[0]]).html(newval);  
            }
        }
    }        
);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

see here **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjdBh/36/)**

in the line

```
$([this, $(this).nextAll('.count')[0]]).html(newval);
```

you add html to both `this` which is `.progress-bar` and to the `$(this).next('.count')`

so just remove the first `this` like so

```
 $([$(this).nextAll('.count')[0]]).html(newval);
```

let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the part that shows %age in `count` div. does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zjdBh/40/) work for you?

Answer (score -3):

Using zero value for font-size does the trick
change your css..

```
 .progressbar {

inline-block;
   font-size:0px !important;
   text-intent:-9999999px !important;
   color:transparent !important
}
```

Comment: There's a difference in English between "does the trick" and "is a trick" - "does the trick" means "this is the exact, best-practice solution"